# How to change "$(this).children" on react?

Tags: reactjs

This is my html, I want to show sub nav when I hover nav 1 or nav 2.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">nav 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub nav 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub nav 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub nav 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">nav 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub nav a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub nav b</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub nav c</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I known I can do it on jquery

```
  $('#menu li').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').css('display', 'block');
  } , function(){
    $(this).children('ul').css('display', 'none');
  });
```

But how to do it on react?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. Please avoid using jQuery within React since this is a bad practice.

React is all about components which you can easily achieve the very same result:

```js
class CollapsibleItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {
      showContent: false,
    }
    
    this.toggleHover = this.toggleHover.bind(this)
  }
  
  toggleHover() {
    this.setState({
      showContent: !this.state.showContent,
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    const { showContent } = this.state
    
    return (
      <li
        onMouseOver={this.toggleHover}
        onMouseOut={this.toggleHover}
      >
        {this.props.name} 
        {showContent && this.props.children}
      </li>
    )
  }
}

const App = () => 
  <div>
    <ul>
      <CollapsibleItem name="Nav 1">
        <ul>
          <li>Sub nav 1</li>
          <li>Sub nav 2</li>
          <li>Sub nav 3</li>
        </ul>
      </CollapsibleItem>
      <CollapsibleItem name="Nav 2">
        <ul>
          <li>Sub nav 4</li>
          <li>Sub nav 5</li>
          <li>Sub nav 6</li>
        </ul>
      </CollapsibleItem>
    </ul>
  </div>

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, no wonder I can't found something like "$(this).children" at react official documentation. Now I get it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid to use jQuery or even ReactJS when you can do it with two lines of CSS ;)

```css
#menu ul { display: none; }
#menu li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">nav 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub nav 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub nav 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub nav 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">nav 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub nav a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub nav b</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub nav c</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this also a great way to solve my problem! :)